# Can I upgrade the SSD on the Early 2015 13" Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I do not want to go to Apple to upgrade the SSD on my macbook pro 12,1. Is there a third-party SSD that would work with my Macbook Pro? I currently have the 128GB model, and it is running out of space. I am looking to purchase either a 256GB or 512GB SSD that will run at *comparable speeds* to the current SSD. I know Apple has tried to stop users from upgrading to third party SSDs, I am more than comfortable upgrading these things by myself, but I just don't know if there is any compatibility. Thanks.

Comment: Officially, it is not possible for an end user to upgrade the storage after purchase.  Also I've not yet seen a compatible 3rd party PCIe 2.0 4-Lane SSD of the type used by Apple in the Early 2015 13" MacBook Pro available other then by Apple.

Answer (score 5):

Answer in 2020: A [MacRumors forum post](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/upgrading-2013-2014-macbook-pro-ssd-to-m-2-nvme.2034976/) details the process of using an adapter along with a generic M.2 NVMe SSD drive to replace the OEM drive in certain Macbook models, and 2015 13'' Macbook Pro is one of them. The post argues that this method is much better than using OWC/Transcend drives due to price and quality. I have personally followed the guide and completed the replacement, and 3 months in everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here at MCE USA.
They offer SSD Blades for MacBook Pro Late 2013 - Early 2015 from 256GB up to 1TB.
http://store.mcetech.com/mm/merchant.mvc?Store_Code=MTOS&Screen=CTGY&Category_Code=PCIEFLASH

OWC/MacSales doesn't have any yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like OWC has finally managed to build replacement SSDs for the new macbook pro retina models, including the 13" early 2015 model (480 gb model):
http://www.owcshop.eu/catalog/product_info.php/aura-macbook-retina-mid2013-till-2015-480gb-preord-p-1380#.Vup7ExIrK-Y

And a 1 TB model too:
http://www.owcshop.eu/catalog/product_info.php/aura-macbook-retina-mid2013-till-2015-preorder-p-1378#.Vup7OhIrK-Y

Answer (score 0):

Your MacBook may be a bit too new to get an upgrade for, however [THIS](http://nl.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrive/) site provides SSD replacement drives for MacBooks made between 2008 - 2013, depending on the model.

You might contact the company to see if your 2015 MacBook can use any of the drives they sell.

Also, these drives are very highly rated on [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com), so I think you can feel safe that these are a realistic option.

Answer (score 0):

Transcend also has an SSD upgrade for this model. The [Transcend JetDrive 820](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-787). In Europe, it's easier to buy than the OWC brand already mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to go to Apple to upgrade the SSD on my macbook pro 12,1.

That's actually not possible, AFAIK they don't upgrade SDD on existing MacBooks

You can buy 3rd party SSD from Transcend or OWC

Transcend: https://www.transcend-info.com/product/ssd#399

For your model the supported drives are: JetDrive 820, 825, 850, 855

OWC: Aura and Aura Pro X

https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015